# Pentadactyl/Vimperator: howto copy image to clipboard

Tags: images, clipboard, vimperator, firefox-extensions, pentadactyl

My question is about the Firefox add-on Pentadactyl (the question is also relevant to it's parent project Vimperator). In Pentadactyl, there is a way to save an image:

```
;s
```

At this point, you select the image you wish to save, but I want to copy the image to clipboard.

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best solution I could develop (valid for Linux only):

Install [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/), add a script there:

```
from Xlib import display

c = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
x = c["root_x"]
y = c["root_y"]

mouse.click_absolute(x,y,3)
keyboard.send_key("<down>", repeat=10)

keyboard.press_key("<enter>")
keyboard.release_key("<enter>")
```

This script makes AutoKey press mouse-3, and then it presses ArrowDown 10 times (I have a 'Copy Image' there), and finally it presses Enter -- so that pic under Your current mouse position goes to clipboard. You can then bind this script to a key in AutoKey. Works more-or-less stable (don't call it several times at ones).

Comment: All of that with xdotool: `xdotool click 3 key Down Down Down Down Down Down Down Return`.

Comment: @manveru: both these solutions are bad. They use GUI, and the number of menu entries depends on the extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was available when the question was asked, but pentadactyl has a yank hint mode now, accessed through `;y`, after which you select the link or image you want to yank, just like for `;s`

See `:help hints` for all the available hints modes